How to update python to the latest version (3.12.2) in WSL2?
My Python version in my WSL Ubuntu is 3.10.12 and it's not upgrading through these commands even though 3.12.2 is released now. (My WSL Ubuntu version is 22.04)

sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3 python3-pip

Will a particular distribution have control over how much you can upgrade a package? and is it recommended not to do it? is there a command I can run to check how much upgrade my particular distribution will allow for a package? say for python.

Linux distros normally have a Python version tied to the distro and used for various admin scripts. You should not expect that to follow the latest releases of Python. And don't try to force change it because you could break your OS. If you need newer Python versions for your work, install it in user space.

Thank you, do you mean a virtual environment in vs code by user space?

Lots of options, but yes, a virtual environment is probably the most common one, although I'm a fan of miniconda myself.

WSL2 supports the same PPA as ubuntu.
You can simple use:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.12-full -y

I just tested it locally on my WSL2 and it worked.
Then you can use:
python3.12 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate

To install it with virtualenv without breaking other dependencies.
